# use lodash instead of forloop

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I am new to lodash and i want to convert this forloop using i and j to lodash so my coding is reduced.

```
 for(var i =0 ; i < students.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j <marks.lab.length;j++){
                    if(students[i].sID === marks.lab[j].sID){
                        students[i].coding = data.lab[j].coding;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also please let me know if there are any other advantage of using lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the `marks.lab` array by `sID` using [keyBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) to serve as reference. Use [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to return a new array of students wherein it uses [pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) to get the keys that you want from the `marks.lab` cache, and then use [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) to add in all the student properties. Doing it this way ensure that the `students` array does not get mutated.

```
var labs = _.keyBy(marks.lab, 'sID'); // cache by key
var result = _.map(students, function(student) {
  return _(labs[student.sID]) // get the cache
    .pick(['coding']) // This returns a new object
    .assign(student); // Assigns the student object
});
```

```js
var students = [
  { sID: '1', name: 'Ryan' },
  { sID: '2', name: 'Rez James' },
  { sID: '3', name: 'Hazel Charmagne' }
];

var marks = {
  lab: [
    { sID: '1', coding: 'A' },
    { sID: '2', coding: 'A' },
    { sID: '3', coding: 'A' }
  ]
};

var labs = _.keyBy(marks.lab, 'sID'); // cache by key
var result = _.map(students, function(student) {
  return _(labs[student.sID]) // get the cache
    .pick(['coding']) // This returns an immutable object
    .assign(student); // Assigns the student object
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

For the lodash 3 solution, you can simply change lodash 4's [keyBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) with lodash 3's [indexBy()](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_indexbycollection-iteratee_identity-thisarg).

```
var labs = _.indexBy(marks.lab, 'sID'); // cache by key
var result = _.map(students, function(student) {
  return _(labs[student.sID]) // get the cache
    .pick(['coding']) // This returns an immutable object
    .assign(student); // Assigns the student object
});
```

```js
var students = [
  { sID: '1', name: 'Ryan' },
  { sID: '2', name: 'Rez James' },
  { sID: '3', name: 'Hazel Charmagne' }
];

var marks = {
  lab: [
    { sID: '1', coding: 'A' },
    { sID: '2', coding: 'A' },
    { sID: '3', coding: 'A' }
  ]
};

var labs = _.indexBy(marks.lab, 'sID'); // cache by key
var result = _.map(students, function(student) {
  return _(labs[student.sID]) // get the cache
    .pick(['coding']) // This returns an immutable object
    .assign(student); // Assigns the student object
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

---

The **advantage** in using lodash is that it provides a number of utility methods that were already prewritten, which saves resource and developer's time in creating function. As for the case of your `for` loop solution, you could probably say that in simpler cases, a simple `for` loop is better and readable than using `lodash` utility method.

If we talk about performance, you could probably say that solution-wise, **your** `for` loop may take a performance hit since it is O(N^2). You could probably create a `for` loop version for caching the `marks.lab` array and then loop the `students` array again to get the proper output:

```
var labs = {};
var i;

for(i = 0; i < marks.lab.length; i++) {
  labs[marks.lab[i].sID] = marks.lab.coding;
}

for(i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  students[i].coding = labs[students[i].sID];
}
```

The solution above has an O(N) for both loops. Which is closer to the solution that I provided above except for the part where your `for` loop solution and this `for` loop solution above mutates the original `students` array. Mutating the original array *can* be a bad thing when you want to reuse it. Let's tweak the `for` loop solution above so that it prevents mutating the original array:

```
var labs = {};
var result = [];
var i;

for(i = 0; i < marks.lab.length; i++) {
  labs[marks.lab[i].sID] = marks.lab.coding;
}

for(i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  result.push(Object.assign(
    { coding: labs[students[i].sID] },
    students[i]
  ));
}
```

If you compare the `for` loop solution above against the `lodash` solution I provided, then it would have definitely saved you a couple of lines and coding time to write it.

Comment: You are using latest version of lodash. But my project is with version 3.x. thanks for the solution. Did it with _.each function

Comment: Let me try it. before i got a question. What is the advantage of including lodash here if i could achieve the task in two simple for loops.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene check the update for the **advantage`.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you are trying to do a join between two datasets based on the ID of the student. I don't think lodash has a sql-esque join, so in the absence of that you can do the naive O(n^2) implementation like follows.

```
    var new_students = _.map(students, function(stud){
        var matching_score = _.chain(marks).filter(function(mark){
            return stud.sID == mark.lab.sID;
        })
        .first()
        .value();
        var new_student = _.cloneDeep(stud);
        new_student.coding = matching_score.coding;
        return new_student;
    });
```

Note this returns *new* student objects and does not mutate your old objects. That said, if you care about performance and do not mind mutability, then doing a hash join will get you O(n) performance.

```
var sqljoin = function(first, second, first_on, second_on, item_maker){
    var first_dict = {};
    _.each(first, function(f){
        var key = first_on(f);
        if(! (key in first_dict) ){
            first_dict[key] = f;
        }
    });
    return _.chain(second).filter(function(s){
        var key = second_on(s);
        return key in first_dict;
    })
    .map(function(s){
        var key = second_on(s);
        var first_val = first_dict[key];
        var second_val = s;
        return item_maker(first_val, second_val);
    })
    .value();
};
_.mixin('sqljoin', sqljoin);
```